# shell reads file created in windows incorrectly

Tags: linux, shell, character-encoding

Here is my shell script and properties file

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./default.properties
echo $app_name
echo "$app_name =="
```

default.properties

```
app_name=TestApplication
```

At beginning, I create the `test.sh` and `default.properties` file in my intellij on Window. And then I copy then into Linux and execute `test.sh`. However, I get the result:

```
TestApplication
 ==tApplication
```

Then I create the new `default.properties` with the same content using vim. And I get correct result

```
TestApplication
TestApplication ==
```

Using diff command, they are really different and but I didn't found where is the difference

```
diff default.properties default.properties_2
1c1
< app_name=TestApplication
---
> app_name=TestApplication
```

Is there some invisible character in the file I created on windows, or some encode issues?

Comment: This is a high quality question that I recommend for reference. I like the way you documented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a DOS carriage return at the end of the line which assigns the `appName` variable.  This control character causes the cursor to move back to the beginning of the line in most terminals.

Good catch; most askers here don't even realize this is a problem.  The [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a section about troubleshooting this issue.

Many tools on Unix will show the problematic character as `^M` (control-M) or its octal code `\015`; in hex it's character code 0x0D and in decimal it's 13.

In the future, if you absolutely have to use a Windows editor, save with Unix line endings, transfer the file using `ftp` ASCII mode (not a popular or safe option these days), or run `dos2unix` on the file on Unix after transferring it.

Comment: Yeah. I cat the file using cat -v  and I really find there is a character "^M" which should be made in the window editor.

Answer (score 0):

As tripleee already mentioned it is a problem with the different encoding in windows and linux.
You could also encounter problems with special chars like "äöüß"

You can use the linux tool "recode".
Example: change encoding from ibmpc (DOS with cr-lf to latin)

```
recode ibmpc..lat1 test.sh
```

See all supported charsets:

```
recode --list
```

Comment: Though in this day and age, you probably want to recode to UTF-8.

Comment: It is just an example. Feel free to use anything you need/want